# Странное отображение массива объектов в виде строки в javascript

Tags: javascript, массивы, объекты

Имею очень странное отображение массива объектов.

Массив выглядит примерно так:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

После использования `JSON.stringify()` он становится таким:

```
[null,[[1,"01:00 - 01:45"],[2,"02:00 - 02:45"],[3,"03:00 - 03:45"]], null, null, [[1,"01:00 - 01:45"],[2,"02:00 - 02:45"],[3,"03:00 - 03:45"]]]
```

Хотя по идее должен:

```
["1":{[1,"01:00 - 01:45"],[2,"02:00 - 02:45"],[3,"03:00 - 03:45"]}, "3":{[1,"01:00 - 01:45"],[2,"02:00 - 02:45"],[3,"03:00 - 03:45"]}]
```

Код:

```
trainingsTime = {};
public addTrainingTime(time: number) {
if (typeof this.trainingsTime[this.trainingDay] === 'undefined') {
  this.trainingsTime[this.trainingDay] = [this.trainingList[time]];
} else {
  if (this.trainingsTime[this.trainingDay].indexOf(this.trainingList[time]) !== -1) {
    const index = this.trainingsTime[this.trainingDay].indexOf(this.trainingList[time]);
    this.trainingsTime[this.trainingDay].splice(index, 1);
    if (this.trainingsTime[this.trainingDay].length === 0) delete this.trainingsTime[this.trainingDay];
  } else {
    this.trainingsTime[this.trainingDay].push(this.trainingList[time]);
  }
}
}
```

Тип переменной: `this.trainingDay` - строка

Comment: а empty это что? Потому и null

Comment: массив обьектов это когда [ { foo: 'foo' }, { bar: 'bar' } ]

Comment: @RavenTheX по идее так и должно получаться, но почему-то это не так

Comment: «Хотя по идее должен» — не должен. Вы путаете массивы и объекты

Answer (score 1):

Такое происходит из-за того что вы делаете `delete` на элементе массива что удаляет само значение, но не изменяет размер массива и как следствие оставляет "дырку", которая в итоге даёт `null`.

Пример:

```
var arr = [1,2,3,4];

delete arr[1];

console.log(JSON.stringify(arr)); // [1,null,3,4]
```

Что бы убрать элемент испольуйте [`splice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice):

```
var arr = [1,2,3,4];

arr.splice(1,1);

console.log(JSON.stringify(arr)); // [1,3,4]
```

Так же ошибка происходит из-за того что вы назначаете значения напрямую интексам что так же оставляет "дырки".

```
var arr = [1,2,3,4];

arr[7] = 8;

console.log(JSON.stringify(arr)); // [1,2,3,4,null,null,null,8]
```

Comment: Моя проблема заключается не в том, что у меня появляются null, а в том, что массив отображается не верно

Comment: Вам уже несколько раз сказали что вы путаете массивы и объекты. `this.trainingsTime` у вас должен быть объектом, но это массив. Как следствие получается ситуация, описанная мной во второй части ответа

Comment: Вы уж извините, но я несколько раз сказал, что this.trainingsTime объявлен как объект.

Comment: Прекрасно, но `trainingsTime = {};` не то же самое что и `this.trainingsTime = {};`

Comment: На сколько я понимаю вы предлагаете добавить это `this.trainingsTime = {};` в тело функции. Если я так сделаю, при каждом ее вызове он будет обнуляться, а мне этого не надо

Comment: Окей, давайте иначе. `console.log('trainingsTime array:', Array.isArray(this.trainingsTime))` в начале функции что выдаёт?

Comment: Дико извиняюсь, я нашел в своем коде пару мест где объект переопределяется в массив, из-за этого и горе

Answer (score 0):

Вы путаете массивы `[....]` и объекты `{....}`

В массивах числовые ключи идут подряд и начинаются с нуля. Следовательно, если вы присваиваете элемент с индексом 1, в массиве неявно выделяется пустой элемент с индексом 0.

Если вы хотите использовать произвольные индексы, то нужно создавать не массив, а объект и работать как с объектом.

Добавьте в начале

```
this.trainingsTime = {};
```

тогда все последующие записи вида `this.trainingsTime[...]` будут создавать поля объекта, а не элементы массива.

Comment: Самое интересное, что объект у меня так и объявлен this.trainingsTime = {}, но все равно по какой-то причине он создает элементы массива, а не поля объекта. Может я как-то не правильно добавляю новые объекты?

Comment: @Aleksei.C Опубликуйте полный минимальный код, который воспроизводит проблему, со всеми инициализациями и выводом

Comment: Мой массив должен выглядеть примерно так: {"key": [[0, "text"], [1, "text"]], "key": [[0, "text"], [1, "text"]]}

Comment: Он опубликован в моем вопросе.

Comment: @Aleksei.C его нельзя скопировать и воспроизвести то же самое. Это просто кусок исходного кода без каких-либо исходных данных.

Comment: Воспроизводимый код слишком большой, чтобы его можно было бы сюда вставить.